# MySQL-db lib for Python 3.x?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

So, looking for a mysql-db-lib that is compatible with py3k/py3.0/py3000, any ideas? Google turned up nothing.

Comment: Related: [_Python 3 and MySQL_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4960048/617937)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for future plans of MySQLdb, you might want to ask the author (Andy Dustman).
His blog is here: http://mysql-python.blogspot.com/

Comment: For those finding this post 4.5 years later like me, according to your post, mysql-db support for Python 3 is coming soon, based on that blog. Woohoo.

Comment: And for those finding this post 5 years later like me, it looks like that blog hasn't been updated since the above comment, and that Python 3 support for MySQLdb is still non-existent. :(

Comment: And for those finding this post 7-8 years later like me, there is a official connector for mysql here : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ ...history is growing up so slowly...

Comment: in 2019, this answer helped me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724855/4530648

Answer (score 34):

It appears the MySQLdb is pretty much a dead project. However, [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/) is a dbapi compliant, pure-python implementation of a mysql client, and it has python 3 support.

EDIT: There's also [MySQL Connector/Python](https://launchpad.net/myconnpy). Same idea.

Comment: Actually, we could not get MySQL Connector/Python to work with Python 3.3 and SQLAlchemy. PyMySQL seems to work great though.

Comment: `pip install mysql-connector-python` works with Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.1. Concerned about [poor performance](http://charlesnagy.info/it/python/python-mysqldb-vs-mysql-connector-query-performance) relative to MySQLdb.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for it too, but also found nothing, so I ported MySQL-python-1.2.3 to py3k
you can read it here
http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/discussion/70460/thread/61e3a3c9/

Comment: by the way, it's been on GitHub for few years https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3

Answer (score 4):

There are currently a few options for using Python 3 with mysql:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python

- Officially supported by Oracle
- Pure python
- A little slow
- Not compatible with MySQLdb

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymysql

- Pure python
- Faster than mysql-connector
- Almost completely compatible with `MySQLdb`, after calling `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cymysql

- fork of pymysql with optional C speedups

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

- Django's recommended library.
- Friendly fork of the original MySQLdb, hopes to merge back some day
- The fastest implementation, as it is C based.
- The most compatible with MySQLdb, as it is a fork
- Debian and Ubuntu use it to provide both `python-mysqldb` and`python3-mysqldb` packages.

benchmarks here: https://github.com/methane/mysql-driver-benchmarks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working repository for Python 3: https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you're still looking, but you could try this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mypysql/

Comment: Interesting. Note that this is a really minimal lib, with very few features and no PEP 249 support.

Comment: Seems dead. Perhaps pining for the fjords, but not to show for it in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the mysql-connector-python module compatible with Python3:

> http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15667200/dir/rawhide/com/mysql-connector-python3-0.3.2-2.fc16.noarch.rpm.html

Get the "source RPM", unzip it and use it (e.g. put it in your PYTHONPATH, and look at the examples).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using Python 2.x at the moment. It's going to be a while before all Python packages are ported to 3.x, and I expect writing a library or application with 3.x at the moment would be quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official Python 2/3 library, downloadable from MySQL website.
Oracle released version 1.0.7 to public on 29 September 2012.

It's pure Python and works with MySQL 4.1+

See more details here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python.html

I'm currently using it with MySQL 5.5 and Python 3.2 with no problems thus far :)

Comment: Anecdote: had trouble with Python 3.3 + SQLAlchemy + Python Connector.