# Is it still too early to hop aboard the Python 3 train?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still a beginner to Python, so I thought I could as well learn the newest iteration of Python. Especially since it is now 3.1 or 3.2 something.

But it seems like many mayor modules are still only supported by 2.6. Like the python-mysql module; from what I read on http://mysql-python.blogspot.com/ it seems like 3.x support won't be seen in any near future.

Do you use version 3, how do you get around these problems? Should I retreat to 2.6? If not, what should I use to connect to MySQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552499/python-3-x-ready-when/1552551#1552551

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL-db lib for Python 3.0 ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384471/mysql-db-lib-for-python-3-0)

Comment: Is it too late to hop aboard the Python 3 train?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MySQL Connector/Python](https://launchpad.net/myconnpy) is implementing the MySQL Client/Server protocol completely in Python. No MySQL libraries are needed, and no compilation is necessary to run this Python DB API v2.0 compliant driver.

Compatible with Python v2.5 to v2.7 and Python v3.1!

Comment: Thanks for that, but after even more struggling with "old" modules, I've decided to succumb to 2.6 :( It's kinda sad, I really liked the clean-up feeling of 3.x

Comment: And it works with SQLAlchemy as well: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html