# How can I connect to MySQL in Python 3 on Windows?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am using ActiveState Python 3 on Windows and wanted to connect to my MySQL database.
I heard that [`mysqldb`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) was the module to use.
I can't find `mysqldb` for Python 3.

Is there a repository available where the binaries exist for `mysqldb`?
How can I connect to MySQL in Python 3 on Windows?

Comment: Thanks to casevh for the link to the unofficial binaries, but I was too impatient and it appears that the masses are still using python2 ... so I installed python 2.7 and installed MySQLdb from http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL-db lib for Python 3.0 ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384471/mysql-db-lib-for-python-3-0)

Comment: Every time I type pip, my stomach churns. 7 years and counting.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

There are currently a few options for using Python 3 with mysql:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python

- Officially supported by Oracle
- Pure python
- A little slow
- Not compatible with MySQLdb

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymysql

- Pure python
- Faster than mysql-connector
- Almost completely compatible with `MySQLdb`, after calling `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cymysql

- fork of pymysql with optional C speedups

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

- Django's recommended library.
- Friendly fork of the original MySQLdb, hopes to merge back some day
- The fastest implementation, as it is C based.
- The most compatible with MySQLdb, as it is a fork
- Debian and Ubuntu use it to provide both `python-mysqldb` and`python3-mysqldb` packages.

benchmarks here: https://github.com/methane/mysql-driver-benchmarks

Comment: `pip install mysqlclient` *just worked* for me! thanks for the comprehensive list of options.

Comment: `mysqlclient` just worked for my Python3.4+Django+Passenger+Dreamhost install.

Comment: [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3+mysqldb&searchon=names&suite=yakkety&section=all) has mysqlclient [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=wheezy&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python3+mysqldb) not

Comment: Looks like mysqlclient is in debian `testing` as `python3-mysqldb`, but it's not in `stable`. So it will be in the next version.

Comment: for install mysql connector on ubuntu you can use a apt like `sudo apt-get install python3-mysql.connector`

Comment: Just added a post on [how to install mysqlclient](https://gettips.typlog.com/2017/how-to-use-mysql-in-python3)

Comment: This comment lists options and talks about compatibility with MySQLdb, but does not list MySQLdb as an option. Is that intentional? Is MySQLdb no longer an option?

Comment: Correct. The author of `MySQLdb` has not made it compatible with Python 3. (So you can't `pip install MySQLdb` on Python 3.) Many distributions now alias the `MySQLdb` package to the `mysqlclient` fork. If you are used to used to using `MySQLdb`, install `mysqlclient` instead.

Comment: Trying to install pymysql often results in  [difficult dependency issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526708/fatal-error-python-h-no-file-or-directory). In my case (Mint 18, Python 3.6), these were fixed by installing `libpython3.6-dev`.

Comment: mysqlclient is preferable inasmuch as you can import it as "MySQLdb"

Comment: @Shift'NTab , how do you connected to server? I have use this `db = pymysql.connect("servername","ndUser","ndpass","BM" )` and the `cursor = db.cursor()` , but it's giving me timeout error.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare you can check their connection example on github https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

Comment: I also needed to install `libmysqlclient-dev` (`apt install libmysqlclient-dev`), before: `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 73):

You should probably use **[pymysql](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/) - Pure Python MySQL client** instead.
It works with Python 3.x, and doesn't have any dependencies.

> This pure Python MySQL client provides a DB-API to a MySQL database by talking directly to the server via the binary client/server protocol.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> import pymysql
> conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock', user='root', passwd=None, db='mysql')
> cur = conn.cursor()
> cur.execute("SELECT Host,User FROM user")
> for r in cur:
>     print(r)
> cur.close()
> conn.close()
> ```

Comment: unfortunately it's a ZERO-documented library which happen to *just not work*

Comment: @Lohoris: How come I'm using it without any problems?

Comment: I have not been able to install this on Windows 7 with Python 3.x. Anyone know how?

Comment: Python version 3.3.1 here and it doesn't install. Complains about missing module called `constants`.

Comment: @Pius Because you're doing it wrong. Just checked and it works.

Comment: @Pius Ah, I've never actually *installed* it, sorry. The standard `setup.py` may be broken. What I did is download the source, run `build-py3k.sh` and import from the directory.

Comment: @Pius I think you're installing the Python2 version. Trying "pip install pymysql3", instead of "pip install pymysql"

Comment: This is also the only useable connector for Maya which uses 2.7 internally but the MySQLdb connector is compiled with a different version of visual studio and is not compatible... so you need to use the pure python connector which has no compiled components so it works :)

Answer (score 11):

if you want to use MySQLdb first you have to install pymysql on your pc by typing in cmd of windows

```
pip install pymysql
```

then in python shell, type

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost" , "root" , "password")
```

this will establish the connection.

Answer (score 7):

I also tried using pymysql (on my Win7 x64 machine, Python 3.3), without too much luck. I downloaded the .tar.gz, extract, ran "setup.py install", and everything seemed fine. Until I tried connecting to a database, and got "KeyError [56]". An error which I was unable to find documented anywhere.

So I gave up on pymysql, and I settled on the [Oracle MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html).

It comes as a setup package, and works out of the box. And it also seems decently documented.

Comment: I was using MySQLdb and that works great, but clearly, I would expect this to become the defacto standard over time.

Answer (score 6):

**Summary**

> [Mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) is the best alternative(IMHO) because it works flawlessly with
>   **Python 3+**, follows expected **conventions** (unlike mysql
>   connector), uses the object name **mysqldb** which enables convenient porting of 
>   existing software and is used by **Django** for Python 3 builds

Is there a repository available where the binaries exist for mysqldb?

> **Yes.**  mysqlclient allows you to use mysqldb functions.  Though,
>   remember this is **not a direct port** by mysqldb, but a build by mysqlclient

How can I connect to MySQL in Python 3 on Windows?

> pip install mysqlclient

Example

```
#!/Python36/python
#Please change above path to suit your platform.  Am running it on Windows
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(user="my-username",passwd="my-password",host="localhost",db="my-databasename")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from my-table-name")
data=cursor.fetchall()
for row in data :
    print (row)
db.close()
```

I can't find mysqldb for Python 3.

> mysqldb has not been ported yet

Answer (score 5):

Untested, but there are some binaries available at:

[Unofficial Windows Binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score 5):

PyMySQL gives MySQLDb like interface as well. You could try in your initialization:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Also there is a port of mysql-python on github for python3.

https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3

Answer (score 2):

Oracle/MySQL provides an official, pure Python DBAPI driver: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

I have used it with Python 3.3 and found it to work great. Also works with SQLAlchemy.

See also this question: [Is it still too early to hop aboard the Python 3 train?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805038/is-it-still-too-early-to-hop-aboard-the-python-3-train)

Answer (score 1):

On my mac os maverick i try this:

- In Terminal type:

  1)**mkdir -p ~/bin ~/tmp ~/lib/python3.3 ~/src**     2)**export  TMPDIR=~/tmp**
  3)**wget -O ~/bin/2to3**
  4)**http://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/60c831305e73/Tools/scripts/2to3**
  5)**chmod 700 ~/bin/2to3**     6)**cd ~/src**     7)**git clone https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL.git**       8)**cd PyMySQL/**
  9)**python3.3 setup.py install --install-lib=$HOME/lib/python3.3
  --install-scripts=$HOME/bin**

After that, enter in the python3 interpreter and type:

1. > > > **import pymysql**. 
   > > >       If there is no error your installation is ok. For verification write a script to connect to mysql with this form:
2. *# a simple script for MySQL connection 
       import pymysql db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="**",  db="biblioteca") #Sure, this is
   information for my db    # close the connection     db.close ()*

Give it a name ("con.py" for example) and save it on desktop. In Terminal type "cd desktop" and then
$python con.py
If there is no error, you are connected with MySQL server. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This does not fully answer my original question, but I think it is important to let everyone know what I did and why.

I chose to continue using python 2.7 instead of python 3 because of the prevalence of 2.7 examples and modules on the web in general.

I now use both mysqldb and mysql.connector to connect to MySQL in Python 2.7.  Both are great and work well.  I think mysql.connector is ultimately better long term however.

Comment: I'm curious if you are still using Python 2.7.  In general, I think that it's really important to make the transition to Python 3, and I've been surprised to see so many programmers opting for Python 2.7 for new projects. How did things work out?

Comment: @vy32 I think you might be less surprised by developers choosing py27 if you consider that many server OSes don't directly support Python 3. Red Hat Enterprise Linux was still being bundled with Python **2.6** until the most recent version, and even that one only has py27.

Comment: Another reason to use python 2.7 is because Maya (which supports python) uses 2.7 internally.  BTW... if you also need to connect to MySQL through python in Maya... use the pure python mysql connector.

Answer (score 0):

CyMySQL
https://github.com/nakagami/CyMySQL

I have installed pip on my windows 7, with python 3.3
just 
pip install cymysql

(you don't need cython)
quick and painless

Answer (score 0):

I'm using cymysql with python3 on a raspberry pi
I simply installed by:
sudo pip3 install cython
sudo pip3 install cymysql
where cython is not necessary but should make cymysql faster

So far it works like a charm and very similar to MySQLdb

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick tutorial on how to get Python 3.7 working with Mysql 
Thanks to all from who I got answers to my questions
- hope this helps somebody someday.
----------------------------------------------------
**My System:** 
Windows Version:  Pro  64-bit

**REQUIREMENTS.. download and install these first...**
**1. Download Xampp..**
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
**2. Download Python**
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

--------------
//METHOD
--------------
Install xampp first after finished installing - install Python 3.7.
Once finished installing both - reboot your windows system.
Now start xampp and from the control panel - start the mysql server.
Confirm the versions by opening up CMD and in the terminal type

```
c:\>cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin

c:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -h localhost -v
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 2
Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
```

This is to check the MYSQL version

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin>python
Python 3.7.0b3 (v3.7.0b3:4e7efa9c6f, Mar 29 2018, 18:42:04) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

This is to check the Python version
Now that both have been confirmed type the following into the CMD...

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin>pip install pymysql
```

After the install of pymysql is completed.
create a new file called "testconn.py" on your desktop or whereever for quick access.
Open this file with sublime or another text editor and put this into it.
Remember to change the settings to reflect your database.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb() 

import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(user="yourusernamehere",passwd="yourpasswordhere",host="yourhosthere",db="yourdatabasehere")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from yourmysqltablehere")
data=cursor.fetchall()
for row in data :
    print (row)
db.close()
```

Now in your CMD - type

```
c:\Desktop>testconn.py
```

And thats it... your now fully connected from a python script to mysql...
Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

import pymysql

#open database connection

db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","","ornament")

## prepare a cursor object using cursor() method

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM item"

cursor.execute(sql)

## Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.

results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
item_title = row[1]
comment = row[2]
print ("Title of items are the following  = %s,Comments are the following = %s" % 
(item_title, comment))

Answer (score 0):

**follow these steps:**

1. import pymysql
2. install

   **python -m pip install PyMySQL**

   **python -m pip install PyMySQL[rsa]**

   **python -m pip install PyMySQL[ed25519]**

finally try again to install **pip install mysql-connector**.

these steps solved my error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).