# Django and mysql problems on Mavericks

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I'm running Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks. I'm trying to run django under python 3. Because I'm running Python 3 I have to get the official connector from the mysql devs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) gave it a quick test in the shell and it works.

I ran `python manage.py runserver` with `"mysql.connector.django"` as the engine having seen an example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html)  and I got this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named mysql.connector.django.base
```

So I switch back to the default using `"django.db.backends.mysql"` as my engine and I get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I have no idea how to proceed. I can't install MySQLdb because I'm running my django install under python3 and it's unsupported, but I'm definitely missing something with this connector.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3 and mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql)

Comment: [Priyank's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb) combined with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib) solved the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For python 2.7, 3.3+ there is a driver called [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) that works with django 1.8

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

And in your settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': '',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',      
    }
}
```

Here's the official django documentation about the mysql drivers:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Comment: To get this to work I had to add a symlink to libmysqlclient. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib)

Comment: I have spent nearly a day trying to get this to work - and this has been the only solution to resolve the issue! [+]

Comment: I get the error when installing via pip3: `OSError: mysql_config not found`

Comment: I still can't get this to work...
I'm using ```'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',```
pip freeze:
asgiref==3.2.3
Django==3.0
django-mysql==3.3.0
dnspython==1.16.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.19
mysqlclient==1.4.6
protobuf==3.6.1
PyMySQL==0.9.3
pyodbc==4.0.28
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0

I'm still getting the same Error:
```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.mysql' isn't an available database backend.```