# Django migrate returning 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models - site, organization and institution defined as below. The problem is that when I run the migrations I get the following error:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 42, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'None) NOT NULL, `site_uid` varchar(50) NOT NULL)' at line 1")
```

site.py

```
class Site(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Incomplete', 'Incomplete')
    )

    uid = models.CharField(primary_key=True,  max_length=50, unique=True, editable=False)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default='')
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, default='')
    full_address = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=False, default='')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, default='Pending')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site_name
```

organization.py

```
class Organization(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Incomplete', 'Incomplete')
    )

    uid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default='')
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, default='')
    full_address = models.TextField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, default='Pending')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.organization_name
```

institution.py

```
class Institution(models.Model):

    uid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    organization_uid = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                         editable=False)
    site_uid = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uid
```

Is there any problem in the way I have defined the models? Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

edit:

This is the initial migration file:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Institution',
            fields=[
                ('uid', models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, max_length=50, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Organization',
            fields=[
                ('uid', models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, max_length=50, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('organization_name', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100)),
                ('country', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100)),
                ('postcode', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=20)),
                ('full_address', models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=50, null=True)),
                ('status', models.CharField(choices=[(b'Active', b'Active'), (b'Pending', b'Pending'), (b'Incomplete', b'Incomplete')], default=b'Pending', max_length=20)),
                ('created_on', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.datetime_safe.date.today)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Site',
            fields=[
                ('uid', models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=50, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('site_name', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100)),
                ('country', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100)),
                ('postcode', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=20)),
                ('full_address', models.TextField(default=b'', max_length=200)),
                ('status', models.CharField(choices=[(b'Active', b'Active'), (b'Pending', b'Pending'), (b'Incomplete', b'Incomplete')], default=b'Pending', max_length=20)),
                ('created_on', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.datetime_safe.date.today)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Transaction',
            fields=[
                ('uid', models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=50, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('created_on', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.datetime_safe.date.today)),
                ('amount', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=b'0', max_digits=6)),
                ('currency', models.CharField(blank=True, default=b'\xc2\xa3')),
                ('site_uid', models.ForeignKey(db_column=b'site_uid', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='main.Site')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('uid', models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, max_length=50, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True)),
                ('email', models.CharField(blank=True, default=b'', max_length=20)),
                ('password', models.CharField(blank=True, default=b'', max_length=20)),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('full_address', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('country', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('status', models.CharField(choices=[(b'Active', b'Active'), (b'Pending', b'Pending'), (b'Locked', b'Locked'), (b'Validated', b'Validated')], default=b'Pending', max_length=20)),
                ('role', models.CharField(choices=[(b'SuperAdmin', b'SuperAdmin'), (b'OrganizationAdmin', b'OrganizationAdmin'), (b'SiteAdmin', b'SiteAdmin'), (b'User', b'User')], default=b'User', max_length=20)),
                ('date_joined', models.DateField(default=django.utils.datetime_safe.date.today)),
                ('password_last_updated', models.DateField(default=django.utils.datetime_safe.date.today)),
                ('last_logged_in', models.DateField(default=django.utils.datetime_safe.date.today)),
                ('institution', models.ForeignKey(db_column=b'institution_uid', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='main.Institution')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='institution',
            name='organization_uid',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column=b'organization_uid', editable=False, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='main.Organization'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='institution',
            name='site_uid',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column=b'site_uid', editable=False, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='main.Site'),
        ),
    ]
```

and the issue might be with the way I have declared the FKs as all the fields appear in the mysql table except for the FKs.

Comment: Could you show your migrations file? Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336423/django-mysql-error-on-migrate

Comment: @Nuts yes, I have tried, it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Why is there no `default=uuid.uuid4` for Site uid

Comment: @hassan thank you for spotting that! but i still get the same error

Comment: the problem is with this statement `created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today)`  please change that too `created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today())` and delete the current migration file and re run the makemigration statement . or you can edit the migration file

Comment: @NakulNarayanan made the changes but I'm still having the migration issue

Comment: @keyko Did you delete the old migration file and re run the makemigration command ?

Comment: @NakulNarayanan yes, I deleted the old ones then run again `makemigrations` and then `migrate`

Comment: are you getting the same error ??

Comment: yes, precisely the same one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179891/discussion-between-nakul-narayanan-and-keykoyume).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my models was that I have defined a field called `currency` in one of my models where I have set a default value of `'£'` for a *charField*

```
currency = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, default='£')
```

Thank you all for the help!