# Django migrate error _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv, mysql-python

TL;DR: python versions conflicts, i think that the python i downloaded and compiled (3.6) can't use this package (libmysqlclient-dev) to make migrations to mysql. only the system's default python (3.4) can.

my ubuntu server came with python 3.4, all of my django work and other work depend on 3.6. i have learned that upgrading system python is a bad idea, so i compiled python 3.6 (with `altinstall`).

when i ran `python3.6 manage.py migrate` it gave me this mysql error:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL)' at line 1")

i tried virtual environment and normal python 3.6, both gave the same error, and i made sure that `libmysqlclient-dev` and `mysqlclient` are installed.

as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336423/django-mysql-error-on-migrate) suggests, the problem is with `libmysqlclient-dev` because it's installed via `apt-get` not `pip` so i guess it's only compatible with the default python (3.4 that came with the system) or my compiled python 3.6 isn't allowed to use it, because when i made a dummy django project with python3.4 (system's default) and attempted `python3.6 manage.py migrate` on the same mysql database with the same user, it worked!

AGAIN: my problem is that the manually compiled python 3.6 can't use `libmysqlclient-dev` that has been installed by `apt-get`, only 3.4 can

reference: [Django MySQL error on migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336423/django-mysql-error-on-migrate)

**UPDATE**
i came up with a work around but it's not efficient. i downgraded Django to 2.0.9 and it (`python manage.py migrate`) worked. but this problem could appear again with a different package.

Comment: Have you tried creating a virtualenvironment and installing mysqlclient there?

Comment: yes, i've mentioned that

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? It seems highly likely that the version you have is no longer supported by Django.

Comment: Server version: 5.5.61-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
mysql --version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.61, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Answer (score 16):

Django 2.1.* requires MySQL 5.6 or higher. It broke the compatibility by mapping `DateTimeField` to `datetime(6)`.

You can patch Django MySQL data type mapper. Put this to the top of your `settings.py`

```
from django.db.backends.mysql.base import DatabaseWrapper
DatabaseWrapper.data_types['DateTimeField'] = 'datetime' # fix for MySQL 5.5
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a major difference in the support for `django 2.0.*` vs `django 2.1.*`

AS per [Django 2.0.* MySQL Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#version-support)

> Django supports MySQL 5.5 and higher.

As per [Django 2.1.* MySQL Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#version-support)

> Django supports MySQL 5.6 and higher.

Check you MySQL version with: `mysql -V` and use the correct django version.

Comment: `pip install django==2.0.*`

Comment: This answer just solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931065/django-mysql-error-when-running-tests-in-a-virtualenv?noredirect=1#comment96626819_54931065

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.backends.mysql.base import DatabaseWrapper
DatabaseWrapper.data_types['DateTimeField'] = 'datetime' # fix for MySQL 5.5
```

Solved my problem!

Thanks Luka Zakrajšek