# Django - can't do migrations, MySQL 5.7.19, Py 3.6.2

Tags: php, python, mysql, django, django-migrations

Help I'm stuck in Django hell!
I'm trying to learn Django and I'm trying to set up a test site on my own computer (MacOS 10.12.6).  My version of Python is 3.6.2 with Django 1.11.4 and MySQL 5.7.19.

I am at the point where I want to do:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

BUT... it doesn't work... I have installed **mysql-connector 2.1.6** and that particular version seems to have a bug [which is documented here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86105). The error posted looks like mine.  MySQL said the bug was fixed in version 2.1.7, but I can't download that with pip and I don't see it anywhere.  The only other version higher that pip sees is 2.2.3 and that doesn't install at all.

I found other [instructions that suggested using mysqlclient](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419210/django-and-mysql-problems-on-mavericks)), but even that doesn't work.  I get this error...

```
pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/d9/z3yxpfl505s_jwtty_x3576h0000gn/T/pip-build-8vj20eqa/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/d9/z3yxpfl505s_jwtty_x3576h0000gn/T/pip-build-8vj20eqa/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/private/var/folders/d9/z3yxpfl505s_jwtty_x3576h0000gn/T/pip-build-8vj20eqa/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/d9/z3yxpfl505s_jwtty_x3576h0000gn/T/pip-build-8vj20eqa/mysqlclient/
```

I hope someone can help me get past this since I'm definitely stuck at this point.  Thank you in advance!

-b

Comment: Are you sure you have MySQL or the tools installed?

Comment: I think I figured it out... I had to add the path to mysql_config to $PATH... Can I delete a question if I solve it myself :/

Comment: Don't delete the question. This question might be helpful o future readers. Accept the answer which helped you most. @BSmith

Comment: YES -- that's what it was... I needed to add "/usr/local/mysql/bin" to my $PATH and I was able to get mysqlclient installed.  Once I changed the ENGINE setting back to 'django.db.backends.mysql' -- I was able to get past this step.  I'll vote to delete it if no one finds it useful.

Comment: Sorry, the posted answer Mohideen had nothing to do with this problem, but  appreciate everyone's help (and eyes).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have issue in your Mysql connectors.. so try these,

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

mysql-config is in a different package, which can be installed from:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the clue, unfortunately, I understood it after I posted my question:

```
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
```

I thought that the path to the MySQL executables was correct, but it wasn't.  I added this to my .bash_profile file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

and then changed the ENGINE setting in settings.py back to:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

..and the migrations went fine.