# 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend Django Version 3.+

Tags: python, mysql, django

After Upgrading the version of Django from 2.+ to 3.+ then the error occur after upgrading.

```
 Django==3.0.4
 mysql-connector==2.2.9
 mysql-connector-python==8.0.19
 mysqlclient==1.4.6
 PyMySQL==0.9.3
```

====

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
      'NAME': 'eetech_analytics',
      'USER': 'root',
      'PASSWORD': 'qwerty!123',
      'HOST':'localhost',
      'OPTIONS': {
          'use_pure': True,
          'autocommit': True,
      },
   }
}
```

and this is the error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available 
database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of: 
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: Add your database configuration to get more help. From the error message it seems like your configuration has not been done properly.

Comment: Done, I added the database config.

Comment: Shouldn't the `ENGINE` be `django.db.backends.mysql` instead?

Comment: But in django 2.+ that was the *engine* I used and it is working fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django and mysql problems on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419210/django-and-mysql-problems-on-mavericks)

Comment: also check  official doc. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#id8