# How to import mysqlclient in python3

Tags: python, mysql

I used

```
python3 -m pip install mysqlclient
```

and it installed successfully.

However when I try to import this into my python code using

```
import mysqlclient as sql
```

It comes up with

```
ImportError: No module named 'mysqlclient'
```

What am I doing wrong that doesn't allow me to import this module.

Comment: On what OS? Win/Linux/OS X?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529958/python3-mysqlclient-1-3-6-aka-pymysql-usage)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting an **error**, then probably the package is **not installed** properly !
Here are some **alternatives** to install `mysqlclient`

**Install from source**

Download source by git clone or [zipfile](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/archive/master.zip).

Customize **site.cfg**

```
python setup.py install
```

### **Note:** The above method is little complex for beginners.

You can visit this site for [Python3.5 and Python3.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) and download the **.whl** package.

Next step is to ***install*** the **.whl** package, (for example) if you have **Python3.5**, you can :

```
pip install mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
```

And use,

**`import MySQLdb as sql`** to import the module.

### **Hope it helps !**

Comment: I didn't have to customize the site.cfg. Just `python3 setup.py` install did the trick

Answer (score 26):

Turns out its

```
import MySQLdb
```

I was previously using

```
import mysqldb
```

which didnt work

Comment: `ImportError: No module named MySQLdb` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS