# In the linux server for production i got error when i try to install mysql-python module

Tags: python, mysql, linux, django

I have a one `django` app , And now  i want send it to production `linux` server but when i try to install `mysql-python` module , I got this error :

```
> error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I know that , I can fix this error with installing visual studio in windows .

but I don't know how can i fix this in linux , and i write this app with python 3.4 .

I search all of stackoverflow , but i can't find anything for my problem .

And i Try C++ compiler for python from microsoft but it can't solve my problem .

when I type `pip install mysql-python` i got this error :

[image]
Thanks

Comment: i install this with easy-install but pip does'nt work too

Comment: and my linux is ubuntu

Comment: when i try pip install mysq-python i got error. i sen picture in my question

Comment: According to your screenshot you are also missing the Python header files. Use `sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev` to install them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysql-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) does not support Python 3. Django recommends using [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient).

See also [Python 3 and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql) .

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Please also note that some packages are required. Not entirely sure which from the following are specific to mysqlclient, but here is a list of the ones that I install in my servers anyway:

```
- build-essential
- python-mysqldb
- libmysqlclient-dev
- python3-dev
```

What is unclear in your question is the part about the ms compiler when the server is ubuntu.

Comment: no , i developing my app on the windows and my production server is ubunutu , thats it

Comment: Thanks for your help man . but why django have these things for mysql . it's not straingforwared like a php :D

Comment: Welcome. Which things, the pip packages? Don't want to start a religious war but php is struggling to reach this functionality for years.