# installing mysql connector for python 3 in raspberry pi

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, raspberry-pi2

I am new at using raspberry pi.
I have a python 3.4 program that connects to a database on hostinger server.
I want to install mysql connector in raspberry pi.I searched a lot but I was not able to find answers . any help would be appreciated

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4960048/1531971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no way to install mysql-connector-python that I used with windows.
for python 3.4 I used the command

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pymysql
```

for python 2.7 you can use following commands

```
 sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install pymysql
```

Answer (score 9):

Before you install, it is important to run update *and* **upgrade**;

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

*Either* install connector for **Python 2**;

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-mysql.connector
```

*Or* install connector for **Python 3**;

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-mysql.connector
```

Comment: **Any suggestions to make this work for a Pi 4B?** I ran all the commands listed above with `Python 3.11.2, pip 23.0.1` installed. It told me that package `python3-mysql.connector` has no installation candidate.

My Pi has aarch64 architecture running `Debian GNU Linux 12 (bookworm)`, Linux Kernel release `6.1.0-rpi6-rpi-v8`, and Linux Kernel version `#1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.58-1+rpt2 (2023-10-27)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use $sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb and it works on pi-3.

Comment: How is this different from any of the other answers? What makes your command line the best?

Comment: it's answering exactly what the person requested for, I thought it's a straight forward answer for someone who might be visiting this page again. Thanks.

Comment: How does this differ substantially from the other answers? It's essentially a duplicate.