# Trouble with pip install MySQL

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

So I've been searching for help with this one but can't seem to find a post with this error.  I try:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Then I get the error message:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/wp/pb_9j5ms3zsbh65y8lllrw6m0000gn/T/pip-build-noAR85/MySQL-python/
```

Then did some googling and came across this ([Python 3 and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql)) and don't know which would be the most used package to download.  I'd be using it with tweepy to help learn databases.  Are they all the same in terms of syntax but written in different libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Answer (score 1):

set-up MySQL for Python

first install pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install -U pip
```

install the required

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

and then install mysql python

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

hope may help you ....