# Django won't make migrations with MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to make the migrations between my database (MySQL) and Django. I used the same parameters in Linux and didn't have any problems. Now I'm using the command :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and I get nothing at all on the terminal. However, the command works if I let the default parameters ( for a sqlite database ). Also, I've noticed that it actually reads the 'settings.py' file because it returns an error if I write something that doesn't make any sense. Here are my parameters, I know for sure that they are correct ( I checked with the MySQL commands ).

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123456789_dont_judge_me',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeZnT.png)

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.5 and Django 2.0.

Do you have any idea where the problem could come from ?

Thank you for your responses kind people !

Comment: What's the error you getting?

Comment: That's the problem.. I get none. Nothing happens ( but there is a laps of 1 second ).

Comment: any screenshot of your command run?

Comment: Just done @JerinPeterGeorge, it's in the post. Thank you for your help !

Comment: In your screenshot, you're using `py manage.py migrate`, it should be **`python manage.py migrate`**

Comment: I tried the two and I get the exact same results for both of them.

Comment: Could you please try python manage.py makemigrations python manage.py migrate And tell me what happens?

Comment: The screenshot is in the post, on the link 'Error Message'. Thank you for your help Pranav!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

> Note: I am not claiming it is best solution, but it is working for me
>   in case of Window10.

Step1 : Install pymysql

```
pip install pymysql
```

Step2: Edit settings.py

```
settings.py
---------------
import os
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb


# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django_test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Step3: migrate it

```
python manage.py migrate
```

you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35888003/5367766)