# MySQLdb cannot connect to MySQL : raise errorclass, errorvalue

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am using `MySQLdb` in python3.5.2 to connect to mysql.  I have done this in many machine and have never faced issues.  In a new machine, I have installed 
MySQL-5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu) version.  And I am using the following code to connect:

```
import MySQLdb
conn=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root", passwd="Abcabc", db="testdb",port=3306)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/tfod_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 80, in Connect
    from MySQLdb.connections import Connection
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/tfod_api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I couldn't figure out any syntax error here and the same code is working in many other machines.  Shall I uninstall MySQL and try again.  This requires me to create multiple tables again.  What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I connect to MySQL in Python 3 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-in-python-3-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pymysql` as `MySQLdb` doesn't have python3 support
check following links

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78215/how-to-connect-mysqldb-in-python-3

or

[How can I connect to MySQL in Python 3 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-in-python-3-on-windows)