# python3.7 sqlalchemy No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-3.7

`pip install sqlalchemy` should be able to install all dependences that it needs.
However, it complains `No module named MySQLdb`. I found that MySQLdb is only for python2. What is up here?

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images of text.

Answer (score 7):

please install this `mysqlclient` using the command `pip install mysqlclient` mysqldb deprecated  in python3 mysqlclient is the fork of mysqldb and added 
python3 support

Answer (score 0):

This post shows all kinds of ways to get MySQL working on Python 3.

[How can I connect to MySQL in Python 3 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-in-python-3-on-windows)