# Python 3.3 Mysql Connector

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL-db lib for Python 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384471/mysql-db-lib-for-python-3-0)

I use python3.3 and can't connect to MySQL, because I don't find module for MySQL connector.

How do I connect to MySQL with python3.3?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384471/mysql-db-lib-for-python-3-0.

Comment: Actually not  duplicate: I searched long and hard for a connector for python3.2. Unfortunately that connector doesn't work with 3.3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a module called [Pymysql](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/) which you may like:

```
"""This pure Python MySQL client provides a DB-API to a MySQL database by talking directly to the server via the binary client/server protocol."""

import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock', user='root', passwd=None, db='mysql')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT Host,User FROM user")
for response in cur:
    print(response)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Any idea how i can use Windows to connect using this？ Seems to be having issue when i use this for python 3.3 on windows

Comment: @User1291223, just remove the "unix_socket=...." from the connect function arguments.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, nobody has ported the C extension module for `mysql` to Python 3, but there are at least two pure-Python modules that work just fine with Python 3 (and also with PyPy, etc.):

- [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/)
- [MySQL Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html)

A quick google for [python3 mysql](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=python3+mysql) turns up a few more (as well as various pointers to these two projects, including previous SO questions that ask exactly the same thing).